# C++ Templates and Memory Allocation

Tags: c++, templates, memory, compilation

I was given the true or false question:

"The compiler creates an instance of a function template in memory as soon as it encounters the function template definition".

My understanding of templates is that the compiler will generate the necessary code when it reads the function definition. I am unsure about memory allocation. Would this be true or false?

Comment: It's a poorly worded and ambiguous question. Who's memory? The compiler's or the program's?

Comment: In principal, you don't instantiate a template until you encounter it's first use (may be an explicit instantiation), where you know the template arguments. But the question is confusing by talking about memory. Maybe it's asking if the compiler needs to "remember" the template, which it probably does. But the term "instance" leads me to believe this is asking about instantiation. In any case, seeing a function template definition is not enough to generate an actual function. You need it's template arguments.

Comment: @RichardHodges I wish I had more information. This was all I was given. I am assuming the program's memory but there was not any more context.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for the clarity. I was leaning towards false. I believe the purpose of the question is to realize the compiler only generates the necessary code/allocates memory when the template is passed arguments, not when it finds the definition. I was confused because it mentioned memory allocation and I had no idea how that played into templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity:

A template is not code. It is a recipe for generating code. That code is generated the first time that other code uses the code that would be generated by the template.

Thus a template function only becomes an actual function when other code uses it (calls it or takes its address).

A function template *definition* is the recipe of how to write the code in the function.

If we assume by "memory", the questioner means "the (possibly virtual) storage in which the program code is located" then I think I would answer **false**.

This is because the function is not written when the compiler encounters the function template definition, it is written upon first use by other code.